# Yahoo YQL testing console and my app are returning different results

Tags: php, api, yahoo, import-contacts

yahoo YQL test console can list my contacts. whereas in my application i see no results. Empty. what am i missing ? (I am using php sdk)

i have set up my yahoo application setting contacts and profile features enabled.

I have been working with yahoo api for 2 days. does it have problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how nice there seems to be a bug with yahoo contacts imported from facebook. thanks for the lost times yahoo!